# Converting date to country requirements

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a calendar in html form and I want to insert this date into MySQL. The default MySQL date is `0000-00-00`. But in my country the format is `DD/MM/YYYY`. So what to do to fix it. Thank you. I am using PHP.

Comment: You can't insert it in format `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: You have to change datatype of column doing this

Comment: Store as MySQL date, and adjust the format at SELECT!

Comment: Yes I changed it from date to varchar(12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL the date format is always YYYY-MM-DD. To convert it to another format, you need to manually convert the retrieved date to the desired format like

`$displayDate=date("d/M/Y", strtotime($mysqldate));`

Comment: Yes that's it I think

Answer (score 2):

You must use one format in your HTML page, and another format in your database.

So, if you want to store a date like this '12/05/2008' into mySql, you must transform it like this:

```
$date = '12/05/2008';
$dateToStore = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$date)));
```

And if you wonder why, you need to replace the '/' with '-' to make php know that the first part of the data string is the day, and then the month (as I think is your case).

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

You cant insert into `DD/MM/YYYY` format. Instead while rendering it in view file you can change into desired format.

```
<?php
    $date = $result['db_date']; // I ASSUMED YOUR DB FIELD IS db_date
    $desiredFormat = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date)); // CONVERTING INTO YOUR FORMAT
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($desiredFormat); // DISPLAYING IT
?>
```

**Method 2**

You can retrieve from database in your desired format using below

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_DATE_FIELD, "%m/%d/%Y") AS date FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: glad it helped you :-)

Comment: can you like my question ? I got -2 and I dont know why

Comment: Sir how to make an html calendar shows you a date as D/M/Y now ? and if a date is already selected how to make a marker on it

Comment: @droidnation then you might accidentally did it.

Comment: @droidnation if you are using jquery UI date picker, then you could refer https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Oh, I really don't know how. What I did wrong exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `STR_TO_DATE`

Try this mysql query :-

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`date`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('10/10/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```